# function does not accept vectors as input

Tags: r, function

I have a problem that really puzzles me but that I find hard to replicate.

I use a self-made function that takes as input a dataset, and a bunch of conditions. It's very similar to `subset()` but somewhat modified. I print the function below. On my machine (Mac OS 10.14.6, R 3.6.0 GUI 1.70) it works. On a computer grid that I need to use (also R 3.6), the following problem exists:

```
subs(dat, a==1)
```

works just fine. However,

```
ca <- 1
subs(dat, a==ca)
```

does not work and it keeps throwing an error that `ca` cannot be found. I have made sure that `ca` does exist but somehow it does not allow vectors or data.tables to be passed to the function. As I said, on my own machine, this problem does not exist, which is why I cannot offer a MWE.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? I am somehow lost, not even knowing whether the trouble is in the machine or the code. So any hint on where to start looking would be more than welcome.

Function & Data:

```
subs = function(x, ..., verbose=FALSE){
  L   = substitute(list(...))[-1]
  mon = data.table(cond = as.character(L))[, skip := FALSE]

  for (i in seq_along(L)){
    d = eval( substitute(x[cond, verbose=v], list(cond = L[[i]], v = verbose)) )
    if (nrow(d)){
      x = d
    } else {
      mon[i, skip := TRUE]
    }    
  }
  #print(mon)
  return(x)
}

dat <- data.table(id=1:5, a=c(3,1,3,1,3))
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the issue `dat <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = c(2, 3, 1, 4, 5));subset(dat, a==ca, b==cb)
  a b
1 1 2
> subset(dat, a==1, b==2)
  a b
1 1 2`

Comment: I run your function with your `dat` and it works in both cases. Are you sure that the problem is not that `ca` is not initialised in the nodes where the code run?

Comment: I print it right before the function starts and it should be initialized. This is what makes it so odd.